# Integral for an inverse with no closed-form solution

Tags: calculus

I have a function that gives $t$ in terms of $y$ that has no closed-form solution for $y$ ([W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%28t%29%2Fdt+%3D+sqrt%28a+-+b%2Fy%28t%29%29)).

I have that $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \sqrt{a - \frac{b}{y(t)}}.$$  Is there some way to set up an integral that I can evaluate that would output $y$ given $t$?

Integrating $dt$:
$$y = \int {\sqrt{a-\frac{b}{y(t)}}} dt$$
Is there anywhere I can go from here?

Comment: It is easy to set up an integral which provides $t$ given $y$...

Comment: Yes, then what?

Comment: You'll never solve this equation in common.

Comment: I fear you are in trouble unless you content yourself with some iterative techniques. These will grant a solution in t even if an approximate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of the cycloid? It is parametrized by

$x = a\dfrac{\theta + \sin \theta}{2}$

$y = a\dfrac{1-\cos \theta}{2}$

and is the solution to

$$\frac{{dx}}{{dy}} = \sqrt {\frac{{a - y}}{y}} $$

Since your equation is

$$\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = \sqrt {\frac{{ay - b}}{y}} $$

we can go like this:

Put

$$\frac{{dt}}{{dy}} = \sqrt {\frac{y}{{ay - b}}} $$

Now let

$$y = \frac{b}{a}{\cosh ^2}\theta $$

We get

$$dt = \frac{{2b}}{{{a^{3/2}}}}{\cosh ^2}\theta d\theta $$

So

$$dt = \frac{{2b}}{{{a^{3/2}}}}\left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{{\cosh 2\theta }}{2}} \right)d\theta $$

and integrating gives

$$t = \frac{{2b}}{{{a^{3/2}}}}\left( {\frac{{2\theta }}{4} + \frac{{\sinh 2\theta }}{4}} \right)+C$$

So your solution is parametrized by ($\phi = 2\theta$, suppose initial conditions make $C=0$)

$$\eqalign{
  & y = \frac{b}{{2a}}\left( {1 + \cosh \phi } \right)  \cr 
  & t = \frac{b}{{2{a^{3/2}}}}\left( {\phi  + \sinh \phi } \right) \cr} $$

In the same way the cycloid is a "deformed" circumeference your solution is a "deformed" hiperbola. The cycloid has a closed form for $(x,y)$ coordinates so you might be able to find one for the above curve.

Comment: I don't think the cycloid has a closed form for $y$ in terms of $x$, just $x$ in terms of $y$ like I was trying to get away from with this question.

Comment: @jnm2 Then at least now you know there is no solution. Yes, I mean $x$ in terms of $y$. However, you get a cycloid running through the $y$ axis if you switch $y$ and $x$. However, see [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?0yrr1ku05cjyl51) a plot of your function (for $\phi \geq 0$) . I seems quite 1 to 1.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer.  No solution even in integral form.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do the next:
$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{a - \frac{b}{y(t)}}} = dt $ then after [integrating](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201/%28sqrt%28a%2bb/x%29%29) you have solution $t(y)$

Comment: I already have $t(y)$.  I'm asking how to set up an integral for $y(t)$.